# How to give Google Analytics access to 3000 users on a single account?

Tags: google-analytics-api

We have a national client, with more than 3,000 agents with their own landing pages within their website: example.com/john-doe-agent/state-USA

They want these agents to have access to the Google Analytics data, but only for their specific landing page. They do NOT want the agents to have have access to the whole company's analytics.

What is the best way for these agents to access to their data without having access to the entire site's data?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Options not applicable in your case:

- **Filtered views**: you could create views filtered at landing page level, however you're limited to 25 views by default so this won't scale.
- **GA Permissions**: permissions aren't granular enough to restrict access to certain content type

Applicable options:

- **Email dashboards**: setup your dashboards to send periodic emails: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1038573?hl=en
- **External Reporting tool**: use a tool like Google Data Studio to create/share those dashboards with specific people (not sure you can create 3000 dashboards though).

Comment: I believe that the dashboard solution is actually the way to go but if they insist on the need of having the data on GA cause of the enrichment you may want to consider duplicating hits to other propertys based on the URL (easy though GTM). So you ll have ALL of them but each agent property has only 1 page.